# ASP.NET webservice responds with Internal Server Error (500) to post and get requests

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery

The webservice code is simple:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void receiveOrder(string json) {
    Context.Response.Write("ok");
}
```

And the jquery calling the webservice is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'http://localhost:50730/GingerWeb.asmx/receiveOrder',
    data: 'test', //JSON.stringify(webOrder),
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data){
        if(data === "ok")
            orderPlaced();
        }
});
```

And yet the chrome console reads in provocative red:

> 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Shouldn't your dataType be "json"?

Comment: I figured it out. For future searchers, the built in page that appears when you just call the asmx page shows that the webservice requires a specially formatted xml text, with (in this case) json as one of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that ASMX web-service need to find *all* input parameters in the request. If at least one input parameter will be not found in the request to the server the web service failed with the status code 500 (Internal Server Error).

The reason is that you send the data in the wrong way. The name of the input parameter of the web method is `json` (see `void receiveOrder(string json)`). So the `data` option of the `$.ajax` should be in the form

```
data: JSON.stringify({json: webOrder})
```

if you use `type: "POST"` instead of `data: JSON.stringify(webOrder)` which you tried before. In the case in the body of the POST request will be `json=theVlue` instead of just `theValue`.

If you would use `type: "GET"` the format of `data` parameter should be changed to

```
data: {json: JSON.stringify(webOrder)}
```

The value of the `dataType` should be 'json'. After the changes the `$.ajax` should work.

Moreover I would recommend you to use relative paths in the `url` option. I mean to use `'/GingerWeb.asmx/receiveOrder'` instead of `'http://localhost:50730/GingerWeb.asmx/receiveOrder'`. It will save you from [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) errors.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Oleg: Your explanation is simple and to the point. I had a similar problem which your explanation solved. I am providing code snippet to help 'searchers' understand what I was facing and how the above helped solve. In short I am issuing a simple jquery (.ajax) from a aspx page. I have created a webservice that gets some data from backend (cache/db) and return's the same in json format.

JS CODE:

```
var parameters = "{'pageName':'" + sPage + "'}"
var request = $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/NotificationWebService.asmx/GetNotification",
     data: parameters,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json"
});
```

ASP.NET Code Behind for Web Service

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetNotification(string pageName)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Notification ns = NotificationCache.GetActiveNotificationForPage(pageName);
    if (ns != null)
    {
        NotificationJSData nJSData = new NotificationJSData();
        nJSData.Code = ns.Code;
        nJSData.displayFreq = (short)ns.DisplayFreq;
        nJSData.expiryDate = ns.ToDateStr;

        return js.Serialize(nJSData);
    }
    return null;    
}
```

It is ABSOLUTELY necessary to ensure that you match 'pageName' variable name specified in web service code with what is sent in your data parameter of the ajax request. I had them different and changed it to be the same, after spending hours, I finally found the right solution, thanks to this post. Also, in my case I am only passing a single "name:value" pair so I didn't even have to use some json De-serialization function to get the value, pageName above gives me only the value.